# How to enable error mode on in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am showing error with error number. In magento 2 we can enable error mode by uncommenting `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in **index.php**

But I cannot found int_set in index.php of magento 2.

How we do this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you first need to enable developer mode by running this command

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Now open **bootstrap.php** at **magento2/app** and uncomment

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: You can accept this answer if it's helpful for you.